# C# simple DHCP server, DNS request?

Tags: c#, dhcp

I am programming a new piece of test equipment for a new product for my company.

One of the tests is ethernet testing and I am told will test like this.

1. Once Product is connected via Ethernet it will request an IP address using the DHCP protocol.
2. The MAC address is to be captured and verified.
3. An IP address is given to the product.
4. Now the product requests the IP address for the hostname "something.something.something.se"
5. The hostname must be checked and verified.
6. The DNS server sends back an IP address for the hostname.
7. The product will then make a TCP connection to the given IP address.

My problem is that I receive a DHCP Discovery message from the product and I respond. I then receive the DHCP Request message for the IP address (Step 1). I send back an IP address and then I hear no more from the product.

If I PING the product on the IP address I gave I get a response so I know the product has received and set its IP address.

I am using a UdpClient to do the communicating and is set-up like so

```
IPEndPoint ProductEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
UdpClient host = new UdpClient();
host.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
host.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 67)); //192.168.0.1 is ip address of PC

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
  if (host.Available > 0)
  {
    byte[] Data = host.Receive(ref ProductEndPoint);

    // Do something with the data
  }
  else
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Any idea why I get no response back for Step 4?

EDIT
I have checked the IP address being sent as the DNS and I have changed it to 192.168.0.1 (was 0.0.0.0) but still no change. As I said I know product got the IP address as I can ping it but it seems to have an issue with the DNS address. I have confirmed this as the product has a flashing red light which I am informed means a DNS request has failed.

Comment: I don't see a programming question here: your DHCP code is apparently returning an IP and the device is using it; the rest is just DNS resolution.  Are you sending a DNS server back with your DHCP response?

Comment: Sorry I added the question, was trying to rush before I went for lunch. Ah so the DNS server is to go in the DHCP response? I have been skimming through some of the RFC documentation but didn't see anything about sending a DNS server on response to IP address request.

Comment: there is no response to SteenT..

Comment: I'm kind of curious why  you're trying to replicate both a DHCP server and DNS server (in code) just for the purposes of testing; why not set up a test DHCP and DNS server and be done with it?

Comment: The test equipment is running on a windows XP machine and must be fully automated. i.e and operator loads a product in, push's a button and away it goes. At then it will either say Pass or Fail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question/problem correct, to fully test all steps, you would have to mock a DHCP server (you're already doing that I think), a DNS server, and finally the service the product is connecting to.

I'm guessing you shouldn't test the part about the MAC address capture and validate, that's not part of the product you're testing.

So when the product requests a IP address from the DHCP, you should make sure the product get an IP number for a fake DNS server too. That DNS server (your code) should then hand the product the IP for yet another fake service when it does a DNS request on the hostname. And finally some more of your code is ready to capture the connection request from the product.

Then you should be able to test all steps.

Comment: I checked my code and the DNS address I was sending was 0.0.0.0. I just changed this to 192.168.0.1 (ip address of the test PC). I still get no more response from the product after giving it an IP address.

Comment: And you're listening to port 53 (tcp/udp), that's where the DNS communication is happening ?

Comment: I did not know about port 53. I modified my code so that once I sent the IP address I would close the UdpClient and create a new one to listen on port 53 like so.

    UdpClient host = new UdpClient();
    host.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    host.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 53));

Still no response

Comment: Try doing it on TCP port 53, I think UDP port 53 is only used for zone transfers (or maybe it's the other way around).

Comment: I tried this and got nothing. - TcpListener tl = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 53));
            tl.Start(); - I kept checking tl.Server.Available to see if there was anything there but got nothing. Also check Pendin() and always got false